# Vicreo Listener 3.0.3 Combination and Trio Keys Not Working

Tags: keyboard

First time trying Vicreo and not able to send simple two or three parameter button pushes from Companion or CentralControl. I'm getting a message:
When you want to use modifiers, use the combination or trio syntax please.

I've tried Combination and three key and both get that message on various combinations of Windows 10 systems. The Vicreo log shows that the message parameters are correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Running the latest Companion beta solved the issue with current Vicreo version 3.0.3

Comment: The password field is now required which the official Companion version I first downloaded didn't support. The password is required even if there is no password set in Vicreo. I have the same issue with centralcontrol.io that hasn't been fixed yet. Reverted testing back to the previous Vicreo release 2.?.?